# git svn clone encounters error when an empty branch is created

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to clone a large SVN repository in order to migrate to git, however the clone operation fails about a third of the way through when it gets to an SVN commit which creates a branch directory but does not add files to it (the files get added in another SVN commit).

The error is:

Filesystem has no item: Working copy path '/branches/secretName' does not exist in repository at /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.10.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5669

I assume this is because git does not track empty directories. How can I get past this?

EDIT:

http://gitorious.org/svn2git

Looks promising, might not have time to play with it for a few days though.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget --stdlayout option?

Try [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) for migration. It is not git-svn-based and translates more SVN concepts to Git (like branches, tags, ignores and others).

Comment: I specified branches directory and trunk directory, and there are no tags.  Indeed there were many branches already before it got to this problematic commit.  I think the issue is that this commit "creates" a branch by adding only the empty directory.  Git is unable to create the branch because on the git side, the empty directory is ignored.

Comment: Also according to http://subgit.com/documentation/lost.html Directories are not versioned by Git, so empty directory created by Subversion commit will not be available in Git repository.  Presumably this would extend to empty branch directories.

Comment: Usually Git doesn't saves empty directories. It's not a Git restriction (it's possible to create an empty Git tree object and add it as a subtree to another tree), it's just a fashion. The only case when Git creates empty directories --- root, if root is empty.

Comment: So does SubGit (omits empty directories but creates empty trees if they are branch roots), it creates commits with empty contents in that case. I mentioned it because it has another engine than git-svn, so doesn't have this bug. git-svn, as I remember (I tried different versions) usually processes empty branches correctly. I think it would be simplier to track the problem if you put here a command you run.

Comment: git svn clone --trunk=trunk --branches=branches <url>